# I could not stop my extension to override chrome://newtab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I could not stop my extension to override chrome://newtab.

I was trying this url override configuration with manifest.json. I was able to have my index page show up on new tab (chrome://newtab ). This helped me during development. Now I think my page is working properly and I want it to only show up as popup when extension icon is clicked. I removed the command of override on manifest.json. However, every time I reload my extension, my extension is still overriding the new tab. I tried to remove it from settings -> on startup -> disable. but when I build my project and reload it to chrome extension, my new tab is modified again, and this (settings -> on startup ) shows that my extension gained control again.

Below is the code I put, and removed. Even after removing this part of code, my extension is still controlling new tab.

```
"chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "index.html"
},
```

Do I have to modify other area in order to completely release the control of new tab?

Here's how my manifest.json look like

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "name",
  "author": "Me",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "XXXX",
  "icons": {
    "16": "16.png",
    "24": "24.png",
    "32": "32.png",
    "64": "64.png",
    "128": "128.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  }, 
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "storage",
    "declarativeContent",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "all_frames": true,
      "matches": ["mydomains"],
      "js": ["content_script.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome. Try removing the extension and adding it again.

Comment: New tab change back to normal after removing the extension, but once I add the extension back, new tab became my index.html. I did some research, seems there's a bug regarding last added extension, I'm not so sure if that's also affecting my case. Hopefully someone can confirm.

Comment: My temporary solution: I have another extension that's also controlling the new tab. I basically removed and uploaded both extension, but in a specific order. Make sure the last extension I install is the one I want to give my new tab control.